# In objective C should i group 10 different protocols in a single header file or every protocol should be placed in it's class header file

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, design-patterns

Which one is the best practice-

I have 10 different types of protocol, which is conformed by 10 different class object (),

classA conform to protocolA
classB conform to protocolB
...

...
You may consider them one-to-one  relation rather than shared protocol by 2 different class.

Now should i group all these 10 protocols in a header file named Protocol.h and then import that header file when any class want to conform his protocol. Like in class A -

```
#import Protocol.h
```

Or should i place each protocol in the header file of the class which contain object that conform particular protocol,like-  `object_name<protocol>` . Like Class X contain object of ClassA which conform to ProtocolA.

```
  @protocol ProtocolaA <NSObject>

    @interface ClassX:
    {
       id <ProtocolA> objectA;
    }
```

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I never did this. If its working then fine. Use that.

Comment: I couldn't understand what you mean.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Declaring a delegate protocol](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11382057/declaring-a-delegate-protocol)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no right or wrong answer to this.  My *personal* preference is generally one protocol per header.  However, if there are two or more protocols that go logically go together and will usually be imported together, you might put them in the same header file.

If your protocols form an API for a framework, that is another reason to put them together so classes that use the framework API can just do one import.

But I would recommend not using a generic name like `protocol.h`, try to think up something more descriptive of what the protocols are actually for e.g. all the protocols and class interfaces for Cocoa are logically imported (nested imports are used) in one header called `Cocoa.h`.

On the second part, I find it generally better to keep protocols and class interfaces in separate headers.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Infact, i am writting an ad SDK for iOS. So there are lots of protocol(having different types of callback like audio/video/animation etc) inside the sdk (around 20), so i am not sure whether i group them in a single header or keep them separate in their container(Class that contain their conformer)  header file. If these protocols are shared by more than 1 class, then it will be a good choice to group them in a single header file, but unfortunately 90% protocol are conformed by only  single class. So can you  please tell me what will you do in this situation.

Comment: @russell You can have the best of both worlds.  Give each protocol its own header and then import them all in an "umbrella" header.  Have a look at Foundation.h as an example.

Answer (score 1):

I would not put all protocols in one header, as each protocol is only needed by one class. Importing the protocol header would give you all protocols.

What Apple is doing in these cases is:

1) Include the protocol in the header of the class where the protocol is used (for example `UITableView.h` and `UITextView.h`):

```
@class ClassX;

@protocol ProtocolX<NSObject>

// Use ClassX here

@end

@interface ClassX

@property (nonatomic) id <ProtocolX> myProtocol;

@end
```

2) Another solution seen in Apple's header is to have an own file for both the header and the implementation (for example `CLLocationManager.h` and `CLLocationManagerDelegate.h`).

Bottom line: I would prefer both these solutions to putting all protocols in one header.

Comment: Hi Tammo, Thanks for your answer.Both Your & JeremyP answer is good. But as Jeremy answered first, i have to take his answer. I have  upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may place protocol in the header file of the class which contain object that conform particular protocol or add protocal as new file.

[Working with Protocols](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH11)